# ViewPager contain separate activity for each page

Tags: android

Any idea on how to set separate activity on each page on ViewPager. I try compatibility package by using FragmentActivity, but on the sample given, it just one type which is ListFragment.

The code I copied from sample of compatibility v4:

```
public class ViewPagerListActivity extends FragmentActivity {
static final int NUM_ITEMS = 10;

MyAdapter mAdapter;

ViewPager mPager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Watch for button clicks.
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goto_first);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
    });
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goto_last);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(NUM_ITEMS-1);
        }
    });
}

public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}

public static class ArrayListFragment extends ListFragment {
    int mNum;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
     * as an argument.
     */
    static ArrayListFragment newInstance(int num) {
        ArrayListFragment f = new ArrayListFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    /**
     * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    }

    /**
     * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
     * instance number.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Cheeses.sCheeseStrings));
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: " + id);
    }
}
```

}

The following execution:

[image: ViewPagerListActivity]

I would like to put activity or view with specific UI and process on each ViewPager, not just one type ListView like on above code sample. for example page 1 is map information; page 2 is combination TextView, EditView and button, Page 3 is Gallery; and so on. Any idea to implement it? or is there any tutorial for this?

Comment: Create your own fragments for example: the first is MapFragment, 2nd is FormFragment and the last one is the GalleryFragment. You can easily gets view inside the getItem() method. Implement the if statement inside the method and returns the actual fragment. if (position == 0){return MapFragment.newIntance()}else if (position == 1){return FormFragment.newInstance()}else if (position == 2){return GallaryFragment.newInstance}

Comment: "Any idea on how to set separate activity on each page on ViewPager." -- Please don't do this. The notion of "activities in activities" (e.g., activities as the contents of tabs in a `TabHost`) was deprecated in Android 3.2.

Comment: @kameny, I will try your suggestion. thanks

Comment: @CommonsWare, if this method would be deprecated in next Android. What is the best way to implement a lot of combination widget on TabHost or even on ViewPager ?

Comment: @Faren: You can use views as the contents of your tabs. Simply make each tab be a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` or something.

Comment: I'm trying to implement that too. If you have any succes on your implementation, please tell me how to do. I'm trying to implement @kameny's solution also.Thank you.

Comment: @CommonsWare What do you suggest if I need usual activity on first tab (textboxes, labels, buttons) and PreferenceActivity on the second tab?

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov: That you don't do it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Why? Because of technical problems or user experience? I want my Settings page  be on one of the page in ViewPager not in the menu. What's the best way to do that in API 8?

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov: "Because of technical problems or user experience?" -- both. "What's the best way to do that in API 8?" -- it is not possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare What's wrong with user experience? I will be using my application and as user I definitely can say that I don't want have menu option that launches settings. Second page in ViewPager would be great solution. Menu option - 2 clicks, second page on ViewPager - one nice slide move.